# How to get an MD5 checksum in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to calculate an [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) checksum of some content. How do I do this in PowerShell?

Comment: What is "some content"? a file? string?

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Starting in PowerShell version 4, this is easy to do for files out of the box with the [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-FileHash?view=powershell-4.0) cmdlet:

```
Get-FileHash <filepath> -Algorithm MD5
```

This is certainly preferable since it avoids the problems the solution for older PowerShell offers as identified in the comments (uses a stream, closes it, and supports large files).

If the content is a string:

```
$someString = "Hello, World!"
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($someString)))
```

---

**For older PowerShell version**

If the content is a file:

```
$someFilePath = "C:\foo.txt"
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($someFilePath)))
```

Comment: `Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "The file is too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size."` As a Linux guy new to Powershell, I'm very annoyed with the struggles I'm having getting an md5 sum, which would be simply `md5sum file.ext` on Linux.

Comment: @StockB Keith's answer below is probably going to handle this better. I agree, there are some shortcomings with powershell.

Comment: I have vanilla PowerShell installed with no extensions, so I broke down and downloaded a command-line md5sum clone instead, which works great. I want to like Microsoft's stuff, but I just can't.

Comment: @StockB vcsjones's method is not buffered... = very memory demanding for large files. I suggest you work with streams: `$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::Open("$someFilePath",[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)))` This gives you **low memory usage** and **no 2GB limit**.

Comment: @davor that keeps the stream open for an indeterminate period of time, so you can't delete the file until Powershell is closed.  `$stream = [System.IO.File]::Open("$someFilePath",[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)` then
`$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($stream))` then `$stream.Close()`

Comment: @StockB Though I'm a happy Windows developer, I feel with you. While Windows has grown to be a great development platform, some basic things are still unbelievably cumbersome compared to Linux / Unix. Scripting and automation is still a major PITA, even though PowerShell was meant to fill that gap.

Comment: @stockb I think Windows is one throwaway text-piping commandline utility away from being being everyone's favorite platform to automate. Or maybe one thousand. Or maybe one package manager? I don't know, but this has little to do with PowerShell, which wraps executables just fine.

Comment: Powershell does not seem to work with shadow copy paths. Had to go with `certutil -hashfile "$path" MD5`. `Get-FileHash` just does nothing. `File::Open` returns `Paths that begin with \\?\GlobalRoot are internal to the
kernel and should not be opened by managed applications.` as error message (good idea to disallow that in a system configuration language).

Comment: Then will it hurt the file if I'm verifying ISO file due to large file size? (~2GiB)

Comment: @Munucial the last option will not using `Get-FileHash`.

Comment: its works, i can use "Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5 my/docs/folder/*" for get md5 for all files in folder.

Comment: Easiest solution imo: switch to WSL and run `md5sum some.file` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 58):

If you are using the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/) there is a [Get-Hash](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/blob/master/Src/Pscx/Commands/IO/GetHashCommand.cs) commandlet that will do this easily:

```
C:\PS> "hello world" | Get-Hash -Algorithm MD5


Algorithm: MD5


Path       :
HashString : E42B054623B3799CB71F0883900F2764
```

Comment: Get-Hash comes from PowerShell Community Extensions. When you can't or won't use the package they've added a cmdlet `Get-FileHash` in vanilla PowerShell 4.0. Vide [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx).

Comment: Note that this (and probably most PS solutions) encodes the string as UTF-16 (little-endian?).

Comment: The link to PowerShell Community Extensions redirects to the CodePlex archive (CodePlex closed down in 2017). Perhaps change to the [GitHub one](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx)? (Is the new master location on GitHub?)

Answer (score 21):

Here's a function I use that handles relative and absolute paths:

```
function md5hash($path)
{
    $fullPath = Resolve-Path $path
    $md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $file = [System.IO.File]::Open($fullPath,[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
    try {
        [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($file))
    } finally {
        $file.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Thanks to @davor above for the suggestion to use Open() instead of ReadAllBytes() and to @jpmc26 for the suggestion to use a finally block.

Comment: This approach is better IMHO than vcsjones' and Keith's because it can take input of files larger than 2GB and it doesn't need any extensions or PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: The `Dispose` call should be in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 19):

Here are the two lines, just change "hello" in line #2:

```
PS C:\> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
PS C:\> [System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication]::HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("hello", "MD5")
```

Comment: The result of this does not equal the output I get with the accepted answer. It computes the hash of the STRING "hello", not of a FILE that would be defined by any path that I replace "hello" with, correct?

Comment: True, but OP didn't ask for a file, and I came here looking for string solution

Answer (score 16):

As stated in the accepted answer, [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-FileHash) is easy to use with files, but it is also possible to use it with strings. For text encoded in UTF-8:

```
$s = "asdf"
Get-FileHash -InputStream ([System.IO.MemoryStream]::New([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($s)))
```

Comment: (Get-FileHash -InputStream ([System.IO.MemoryStream]::New([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string))) -Algorithm MD5).Hash 

Answer (score 15):

Another built-in command that's long been installed in Windows by default dating back to 2003 is [Certutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732443(v=ws.11)), which of course can be invoked from PowerShell, too.

```
CertUtil -hashfile file.foo MD5
```

(Caveat: MD5 should be in all caps for maximum robustness)

Comment: This is a good option when `FipsAlgorithmPolicy` is enabled.

Answer (score 13):

PowerShell One-Liners (string to hash)

MD5

```
([System.BitConverter]::ToString((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider).ComputeHash((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetBytes("Hello, World!")))).Replace("-","")
```

SHA1

```
([System.BitConverter]::ToString((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider).ComputeHash((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetBytes("Hello, World!")))).Replace("-","")
```

SHA256

```
([System.BitConverter]::ToString((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider).ComputeHash((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetBytes("Hello, World!")))).Replace("-","")
```

SHA384

```
([System.BitConverter]::ToString((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384CryptoServiceProvider).ComputeHash((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetBytes("Hello, World!")))).Replace("-","")
```

SHA512

```
([System.BitConverter]::ToString((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider).ComputeHash((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetBytes("Hello, World!")))).Replace("-","")
```

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of examples online using ComputeHash(). My testing showed this was very slow when running over a network connection. The snippet below runs much faster for me, however your mileage may vary:

```
$md5 = [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5]::Create("MD5")
$fd = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($file)
$buf = New-Object byte[] (1024*1024*8) # 8 MB buffer
while (($read_len = $fd.Read($buf,0,$buf.length)) -eq $buf.length){
    $total += $buf.length
    $md5.TransformBlock($buf,$offset,$buf.length,$buf,$offset)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Hashing File" `
       -Status $file -percentComplete ($total/$fd.length * 100)
}

# Finalize the last read
$md5.TransformFinalBlock($buf, 0, $read_len)
$hash = $md5.Hash

# Convert hash bytes to a hexadecimal formatted string
$hash | foreach { $hash_txt += $_.ToString("x2") }
Write-Host $hash_txt
```

Comment: You method overcomes the 2Gb limit of ReadAllBytes from other answers, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: What does the backtick on the `write-progress` line do?  The syntax highlighter doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: @mwfearnley The backtick enables line continuation. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/06/19/powertip-line-continuation-in-powershell/

Answer (score 7):

There is now a Get-FileHash function which is very handy.

```
PS C:\> Get-FileHash C:\Users\Andris\Downloads\Contoso8_1_ENT.iso -Algorithm SHA384 | Format-List

Algorithm : SHA384
Hash      : 20AB1C2EE19FC96A7C66E33917D191A24E3CE9DAC99DB7C786ACCE31E559144FEAFC695C58E508E2EBBC9D3C96F21FA3
Path      : C:\Users\Andris\Downloads\Contoso8_1_ENT.iso
```

Just change `SHA384` to `MD5`.

[The example is from the official documentation of PowerShell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-5.1). The documentation has more examples.

Comment: How to use the Hash-value only from Get-FileHash?

Answer (score 6):

This site has an example: *[Using Powershell for MD5 Checksums](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2008/12/13/using-powershell-for-md5-checksums/)*. It uses the .NET framework to instantiate an instance of the MD5 hash algorithm to calculate the hash.

Here's the code from the article, incorporating Stephen's comment:

```
param
(
  $file
)

$algo = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create("MD5")
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($Path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open,
    [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)

$md5StringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$algo.ComputeHash($stream) | % { [void] $md5StringBuilder.Append($_.ToString("x2")) }
$md5StringBuilder.ToString()

$stream.Dispose()
```

Comment: Good except it doesn't work for readonly files! It needs 
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($Path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)

Comment: If the link ever dies, the answer will be quite useless. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: In response to what I presume was your downvote, I cut and pasted the code from the article here. I didn't do that last year, because I felt it was plagiarism. Adding Stephen's read-only adaptation made me feel it was worth posting.

Comment: @neontapir just to say: posting something verbatim (or with adaptations) is only plagiarism if you don't acknowledge the source.  Copyright (legally or morally) is a separate issue, but I wouldn't tend to worry about that with most code snippets.

Answer (score 4):

This becomes a one-liner if you download File Checksum Integrity Verifier (FCIV) from Microsoft.

I downloaded FCIV from here:
*[Availability and description of the File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290/availability-and-description-of-the-file-checksum-integrity-verifier-u)*

Run the following command. I had ten files to check.

```
Get-ChildItem WTAM*.tar | % {.\fciv $_.Name}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample for right-click menu option as well:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SHA1 PS check\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 '%1'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the snippet that I am using to get the MD5 for a given string:

```
$text = "text goes here..."
$md5  = [Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider]::new()
$utf8 = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
$bytes= $md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($text))
$hash = [string]::Concat($bytes.foreach{$_.ToString("x2")})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return an MD5 hash for a file on a remote computer:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    $fullPath = Resolve-Path 'c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'
    $md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $file = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($fullPath)
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($file))
    $hash -replace "-", ""
    $file.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using @YourWishIsMine answer, I created a simple function that supports all the algorithms for a string input. Because the types follow a specific naming convention, this can be easily extended to future algorithms by simply adding to the "ValidateSet" without any further code changes.

I also added pipeline support as well.

```
function ConvertTo-HashString
{
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)][string]$value, 
            [ValidateSet("MD5","SHA1","SHA256","SHA384","SHA512")][string]$Algorithm="SHA256"
            )
    process {
        foreach ($v in $value)
        {
            $TypeName = "System.Security.Cryptography.{0}CryptoServiceProvider" -f $Algorithm
            #check the algorithm to ensure its a valid type, for ValidateSet
            if (-not ($typename -as [Type])) {
                throw "Invalid Algorithm $Algorithm"
            }
            $Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($v)
            $hash = ([System.BitConverter]::ToString((New-Object -TypeName $TypeName).ComputeHash($Bytes))).Replace("-","")

            write-output $hash;
        }
    }
}
```

example usage:

```
ConvertTo-HashString -value 'hello world' -Algorithm sha256
B94D27B9934D3E08A52E52D7DA7DABFAC484EFE37A5380EE9088F7ACE2EFCDE9

ConvertTo-HashString -value 'hello world' -Algorithm sha512
309ECC489C12D6EB4CC40F50C902F2B4D0ED77EE511A7C7A9BCD3CA86D4CD86F989DD35BC5FF499670DA34255B45B0CFD830E81F605DCF7DC5542E93AE9CD76F

@('a','b','c') | ConvertTo-HashString -Algorithm SHA256
CA978112CA1BBDCAFAC231B39A23DC4DA786EFF8147C4E72B9807785AFEE48BB
3E23E8160039594A33894F6564E1B1348BBD7A0088D42C4ACB73EEAED59C009D
2E7D2C03A9507AE265ECF5B5356885A53393A2029D241394997265A1A25AEFC6
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty print example attempting to verify the SHA256 fingerprint. I downloaded gpg4win v3.0.3 using PowerShell v4 (requires `Get-FileHash`).

Download the package from https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html, open PowerShell, grab the hash from the download page, and run:

```
cd ${env:USERPROFILE}\Downloads
$file = "gpg4win-3.0.3.exe"

# Set $hash to the hash reference from the download page:
$hash = "477f56212ee60cc74e0c5e5cc526cec52a069abff485c89c2d57d1b4b6a54971"

# If you have an MD5 hash: # $hashAlgo="MD5"
$hashAlgo = "SHA256"

$computed_hash = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm $hashAlgo $file).Hash.ToUpper()
if ($computed_hash.CompareTo($hash.ToUpper()) -eq 0 ) {
    Write-Output "Hash matches for file $file" 
} 
else { 
    Write-Output ("Hash DOES NOT match for file {0}: `nOriginal hash: {1} `nComputed hash: {2}" -f ($file, $hash.ToUpper(), $computed_hash)) 
}
```

Output:

```
Hash matches for file gpg4win-3.0.3.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line-command example with both computing the proper checksum of the *file*, like you just downloaded, and comparing it with the published checksum of the original.

For instance, I wrote an example for [downloadings from the Apache JMeter project](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/). In this case you have:

1. downloaded binary file
2. checksum of the original which is published in *file.md5* as one string in the format:

> 3a84491f10fb7b147101cf3926c4a855 *apache-jmeter-4.0.zip

Then using this PowerShell command, you can verify the integrity of the downloaded file:

```
PS C:\Distr> (Get-FileHash .\apache-jmeter-4.0.zip -Algorithm MD5).Hash -eq (Get-Content .\apache-jmeter-4.0.zip.md5 | Convert-String -Example "hash path=hash")
```

Output:

```
True
```

Explanation:

The first operand of `-eq` operator is a result of computing the checksum for the file:

```
(Get-FileHash .\apache-jmeter-4.0.zip -Algorithm MD5).Hash
```

The second operand is the published checksum value. We firstly get content of the file.md5 which is one string and then we extract the hash value based on the string format:

```
Get-Content .\apache-jmeter-4.0.zip.md5 | Convert-String -Example "hash path=hash"
```

Both *file* and *file.md5* must be in the same folder for this command work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get a consistent hash value:

```bsh
function New-CrcTable {
    [uint32]$c = $null
    $crcTable = New-Object 'System.Uint32[]' 256

    for ($n = 0; $n -lt 256; $n++) {
        $c = [uint32]$n
        for ($k = 0; $k -lt 8; $k++) {
            if ($c -band 1) {
                $c = (0xEDB88320 -bxor ($c -shr 1))
            }
            else {
                $c = ($c -shr 1)
            }
        }
        $crcTable[$n] = $c
    }

    Write-Output $crcTable
}

function Update-Crc ([uint32]$crc, [byte[]]$buffer, [int]$length, $crcTable) {
    [uint32]$c = $crc

    for ($n = 0; $n -lt $length; $n++) {
        $c = ($crcTable[($c -bxor $buffer[$n]) -band 0xFF]) -bxor ($c -shr 8)
    }

    Write-Output $c
}

function Get-CRC32 {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Calculate CRC.
        .DESCRIPTION
            This function calculates the CRC of the input data using the CRC32 algorithm.
        .EXAMPLE
            Get-CRC32 $data
        .EXAMPLE
            $data | Get-CRC32
        .NOTES
            C to PowerShell conversion based on code in https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#D-CRCAppendix

            Author: Øyvind Kallstad
            Date: 06.02.2017
            Version: 1.0
        .INPUTS
            byte[]
        .OUTPUTS
            uint32
        .LINK
            https://communary.net/
        .LINK
            https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#D-CRCAppendix

    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Array of Bytes to use for CRC calculation
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [byte[]]$InputObject
    )

    $dataArray = @()
    $crcTable = New-CrcTable
    foreach ($item  in $InputObject) {
        $dataArray += $item
    }
    $inputLength = $dataArray.Length
    Write-Output ((Update-Crc -crc 0xffffffffL -buffer $dataArray -length $inputLength -crcTable $crcTable) -bxor 0xffffffffL)
}

function GetHash() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$InputString
    )

    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($InputString)
    $hasCode = Get-CRC32 $bytes
    $hex = "{0:x}" -f $hasCode
    return $hex
}

function Get-FolderHash {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$FolderPath
    )

    $FolderContent = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object {
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($_)) {
            $FolderContent.AddRange([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_)) | Out-Null
        }
    }

    $hasCode = Get-CRC32 $FolderContent
    $hex = "{0:x}" -f $hasCode
    return $hex.Substring(0, 8).ToLower()
}
```

Comment: Where have you copied the PowerShell code from? [https://communary.net/](https://communary.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider]::new().ComputeHash(
        [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new().GetBytes($yourText)
    ) `
    | %{ [Convert]::ToString($_, 16) }
) -join ''
```

`$yourText = 'hello'` yields `5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592`

Answer (score 0):

Team!
Look at my hash calculation function.

```
Function Get-StringHash {
<#
    .DESCRIPTION
        Get string persistant hash.        
#>
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $True, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "String to calculate hash." )]
        [string] $String,
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "String encoding." )]
        [ValidateSet( 'UTF8' )]
        [string] $StringEncoding = 'UTF8',
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 2, HelpMessage = "Hash algoritm." )]
        [ValidateSet( 'md5', 'sha256', 'sha512' )]
        [string] $Algoritm = 'sha256'
    )
    try {
        #region functions
        #endregion

        $Result = $null

        switch ( $Algoritm ) {
            'md5' {  
                $HashProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
            }
            'sha256' {  
                $HashProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
            }
            'sha512' {  
                $HashProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider
            }
            Default {}
        }

        switch ( $StringEncoding ) {
            'UTF8' {  
                $Encoding = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            }
            Default {}
        }
        
        
        $Result = [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $HashProvider.ComputeHash( $Encoding.GetBytes( $String ) )).replace('-','')

    }
    catch {
        Get-ErrorReporting -Trap $_
    }

    return $Result
}

$String   = 'Some text'
$Algoritm = 'MD5'

$Hash = Get-StringHash -String $String -Algoritm $Algoritm

write-host "$String has $Algoritm hash $hash"
```