# Create a securestring with a password securekey

Tags: powershell, encryption

A Syntax for ConvertTo-SecureString is -

> ConvertTo-SecureString [-String]  [[-SecureKey] ]

I want to use this to create a secure string that is based on a user password, rather than the DPAPI.

I can create a securekey with the following code

```
$key = New-Object byte[](32)
$rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
$rng.GetBytes($key)
```

but according to the docs

> Valid key lengths are 16, 24, and 32 bytes

So it makes it difficult to just type a password in (that would fit into that size)

How would I convert "correcthorsebatterystaple" into a 32byte key? (such that I can then go to another machine and decrypt the secure string, using the same password)

Comment: Seens a bit weird to have a fixed length encryption key ? But could you MD5 hash it - the output of that is 32 bytes. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10521162/478656  - I suspect that's not a great idea from a security perspective, but newer SHA hashes are not 32 bytes long, are they?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler as part of my research to figure this out! it seems to be part of the AES standard - it allows 128, 192 or 256 bits of key length. The theory seems to be that you create a salt, crunch that together with the password and obtain a key from that - I'm still a distance from having code to put in an answer though

Comment: look into PBKDF, bcrypt, or scrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that this works!

```
$salt = "Page-Yet-Rock-Food-Also-Fear-Blind-Rub-Letter-4" # courtesy of correcthorsebatterystaple.net
$iterations = 1000

$plaintext = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $ObjectToEncrypt 
$saltBytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($salt) 

$password = "Bedroom-Woman-Spoon-Quarrel-7"

$deriveBytes = new-Object Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes($password,$saltBytes ,$iterations)
$key = $deriveBytes.GetBytes(32) 

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $StringToDecrypt -Key $key
```

According to the documentation of  [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Rfc2898DeriveBytes takes a password, a salt, and an iteration count, and then generates keys through calls to the GetBytes method.
>   RFC 2898 includes methods for creating a key and initialization vector (IV) from a password and salt. You can use PBKDF2, a password-based key derivation function, to derive keys using a pseudo-random function that allows keys of virtually unlimited length to be generated. The Rfc2898DeriveBytes class can be used to produce a derived key from a base key and other parameters. In a password-based key derivation function, the base key is a password and the other parameters are a salt value and an iteration count.

Comment: I know this is really old, but what is the `$plaintext` variable used for?  It's not used anywhere in the script.  Also, what is the `$StringToDecrypt` variable and where did you get it from?