# Unix md5sum vs Powershell Get-hash

Tags: md5sum

I am trying to generate md5 hash from Powershell. I installed Powershell Community Extension (Pscx) to get command : `Get-Hash`

However when I generate md5 hash using `Get-Hash`, it doesn't seem to match the hash generated using `md5sum` on an Ubuntu machine.

## Powershell:

```
PS U:\> "hello world" | get-hash -Algorithm MD5

Path Algorithm HashString                       Hash
---- --------- ----------                       ----
     MD5       E42B054623B3799CB71F0883900F2764 {228, 43, 5, 70...}
```

## Ubuntu:

```
root@LT-A03433:~# echo "hello world" | md5sum
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  -
```

I know that the one generated by Ubuntu is correct as a couple of online sites show the same result.

What am I going wrong with Powershell Get-Hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not obvious, but you are not hashing the same data. MD5 is a hashing algorithm, and it has no notion of text encoding – this is why you can create a hash of binary data just as easily as a hash of text. With that in mind, we can find out what *bytes* (or octets; strictly a stream of values of 8 bits each) MD5 is calculating the hash of. For this, we can use `xxd`, or any other hexeditor.

First, your Ubuntu example:

```
$ echo "hello world" | xxd
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 640a            hello world.
```

Note the `0a`, Unix-style newline at the end, displayed as `.` in the right view. `echo` by default appends a newline to what it prints, you could use `printf`, but this would lead to a different hash.

```
$ echo "hello world" | md5
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4
```

Now let's consider what PowerShell is doing. It is passing a string of its own directly to the `get-hash` cmdlet. As it turns out, the natural representation of string data in a lot of Windows is not the same as for Unix – Windows uses wide strings, where each character is represented (in memory) as two bytes. More specifically, we can open a text editor, paste in:

```
hello world
```

With no trailing newline, and save it as UTF-16, little-endian. If we examine the actual bytes this produces, we see the difference:

```
$ xxd < test.txt
0000000: 6800 6500 6c00 6c00 6f00 2000 7700 6f00  h.e.l.l.o. .w.o.
0000010: 7200 6c00 6400                           r.l.d.
```

Each character now takes two bytes, with the second byte being `00` – this is normal (and is the reason why UTF-8 is used across the Internet instead of UTF-16, for example), since the Unicode codepoints for basic ASCII characters are the same as their ASCII representation. Now let's see the hash:

```
$ md5 < thefile.txt
e42b054623b3799cb71f0883900f2764
```

Which matches what PS is producing for you.

So, to answer your question – you're not doing anything wrong. You just need to encode your string the same way to get the same hash. Unfortunately I don't have access to PS, but this should be a step in the right direction: [UTF8Encoding class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx).

Comment: After your explanation and with help from a colleague, using Get-Hash with "-StringEncoding ascii" getting me the correct result.

`PS U:\> echo "hello world" | Get-Hash -Algorithm md5 -StringEncoding ascii

Path Algorithm HashString                       Hash
---- --------- ----------                       ----
     MD5       5EB63BBBE01EEED093CB22BB8F5ACDC3 {94, 182, 59, 187...}`

Answer (score 0):

This question is surely related to [How to get an MD5 checksum in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521061/how-to-get-an-md5-checksum-in-powershell), but it’s different and makes an important point.

Md5sums are computed from *bytes.* In fact, your Ubuntu result is, in a sense, wrong:

```
$ echo "hello world" | md5sum
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  -

$ echo -n "hello world" | md5sum
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3  -
```

In the first case you sum the 12 bytes which make up the ASCII representation of your string, plus a final carriage return. In the second case, you don’t include the carriage return.

(As an aside, it is interesting to note that a *here string* includes a carriage return:)

```
$ md5sum <<<"hello world"
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4
```

In Windows powershell, your string is represented in UTF-16LE, 2 bytes per character. To get the same result in Ubuntu and in Windows, you have to use a recoding program. A good choice for Ubuntu is `iconv`:

```
$ echo -n "hello world" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE | md5sum
e42b054623b3799cb71f0883900f2764  -
```

Answer (score 0):

md5sum is wrong-ish, in spite of other people agreeing with it. It is adding a platform-specific end-of-line characters to the input string, on **unix** an `lf`, on **windows** a `cr-lf`.

Verify this on a machine with `powershell` and `bash` and e.g. `postgres` installed for comparison:

```
'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | %{  psql -c "select md5('$_' || Chr(13) || Chr(10) )"   }
echo 'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | md5sum.exe
'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | %{  psql -c "select md5('$_' || Chr(10) )"   }
bash -c "echo 'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | md5sum.exe"
```

Output first two lines:

```
PS> 'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | %{  psql -c "select md5('$_' || Chr(13) || Chr(10) )"   }
               md5
----------------------------------
 1b16276b75aba6ebb88512b957d2a198

PS> echo 'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | md5sum.exe

1b16276b75aba6ebb88512b957d2a198 *-
```

Output second two lines:

```
PS> 'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | %{  psql -c "select md5('$_' || Chr(10) )"   }
               md5
----------------------------------
 68a1fcb16b4cc10bce98c5f48df427d4

PS> bash -c "echo 'A string with no CR or LF at the end' | md5sum.exe"

68a1fcb16b4cc10bce98c5f48df427d4 *-
```