# How to create md5 of string with powershell without using stream

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-2.0, md5

Trying to create md5 hash of a string with powershell that matches linux-generated result... problem is of course that powershell seems to only hash files...

most answers point to memorystream/streamwriter but question is how to do without... Posting this because there is an answer but have to search PowerShell 2.0 to find so will post this solution with link and constrained title

Answer (score 3):

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521061/how-to-get-an-md5-checksum-in-powershell) solves the problem... only found that after a need arose for legacy powershell 2.0 solution... simple search on powershell didn't turn up immediately (or my google-fu is lacking probably)... also, diff vs. linux (if i recall) is about UTF-8 mismatch...

Solution:

```
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$String = "Hello, world!"
$Hash = ([System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($String)))).replace("-","").ToLower()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, there is no direct way or function to create a MD5 hash based on a string (without additional tools or modules for PS). However, you can use a MemoryStream to do it:

```
$stringAsStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($stringAsStream)
$writer.write("MD5Online")
$writer.Flush()
$stringAsStream.Position = 0
Get-FileHash -InputStream $stringAsStream -Algorithm MD5
```

I've found this nice sample on https://infosecscout.com/get-md5-hash-in-powershell/ , which also contains further information about this topic.

If you want a simpler approach using PowerShell extensions, you can use the `Get-Hash` cmdlet in the following module: https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx